# f.select Display all values for selection but only first value is displayed regardless of value selected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, form-for

f.select is displaying all values in my New Form for Mark Up but when a value is chose (ex 1.30) it is not selected and the first value of 1.0 is.

(For Money table)

params[:mark_up])  %>

Comment: Can you improve your question a little better and detail what your looking for. Its currently a little vague.

Answer (score 0):

The reason was because in my schema I had mark up set as an integer and not as a float.